# VBA/Excel - clipboard empty after workbook SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard

After 10 years, I find myself making my first post.  I've search endlessly for a solution to no avail.  I want to:

- copy a range of cells
- save and close the workbook
- user can paste to another application

I haven't even closed the workbook in the code below, yet there's nothing on the clipboard after the SaveAs.

```
Sub Test()
     Application.CutCopyMode = True
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:C5").Copy
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="F:\Test.xlsx"
End Sub
```

Setting CutCopyMode to False yields the same results.  I can paste no problem if I exclude the SaveAs line.

Comment: This is not surprising. I think other workbook operations (e.g. opening) tend to clear the clipboard.

Comment: Try save, copy, close

Comment: Saving the file will always clear the clipboard. This is always the default behaviour. You can try the same thing manually. Copy the range and then click on File->SaveAs

Comment: Also Excel has an uncanny habit of clearing the clipboard so do not rely blindly on the clipboard. Ensure that the copy happens just before you paste it (this means the file needs to stay open) and you give ample amount of time to excel to put the data into the clipboard by using `DoEvents` if data that is being copied is huge or when copying across applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no changes to the workbook after you save, you can simply switch the lines and get your desired end result.

```
Sub Test()
     Application.CutCopyMode = True
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="F:\Test.xlsx"
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:C5").Copy
End Sub
```